# Google autocomplete, second inputs based on first one result

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I need some help with a google autocomplete function. I'm a back end dev so i'm not really good on front end :D

I have 2 autocomplete inputs (pickup address and drop address). We have the working area within berlin, so if the user types the pickup address within berlin area, the drop address can be anywhere in the world else if the user type an address outside berlin into the pickup input, the drop need to be only in the berlin area.

I wrote something like that but is really ugly and not work properly

```
  var polygon;
  var bounds;

  async function autocompletePickup() {
   
    polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: area,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FFd000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      fillColor: '#FFd000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('pickup-address11');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
          alert('The address is within'); 
          autocompleteDrop(1);
        } else {
          // alert('The address is outside of the area.'); 
          // input.value = "";
          // autocompleteDrop(withinArea=false);
        };
     });  
  }  


  async function autocompleteDrop(withinArea) {

    var inside = withinArea;
      
    polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: area,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FFd000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      fillColor: '#FFd000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    if (inside === 1) {
      var input = document.getElementById('dropoff-address22');
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
      input.addEventListener("change", function() {
          // input.value = "";
          console.log(inside);
      });
    } else {
      var input = document.getElementById('dropoff-address22');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(place.geometry.location, polygon)) {
            
          } else {
            alert('The drop off address is outside of our area.'); 
            input.value = "";
          };
       }); 
    } 
  }

  // berlin area
  var area = [
    { lat: 53.804069, lng: 14.124429 },
    { lat: 52.016925, lng: 13.959028 },
    { lat: 52.037322, lng: 11.438104 },
    { lat: 52.888570, lng: 8.804136 },
    { lat: 54.148454, lng: 9.626415 }
  ];
```

Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the Google Places API but I hope the following might prove useful in solving the problem. Currently the code below will simply show a visual indicator ( change text field background colour ) if the pickup & drop-off locations are considered valid.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Places Auto-complete Berlin</title>
        <style>
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:monospace}
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
            form{width:800px;float:none;margin:1rem auto;}
            input{padding:0.5rem;}
            .ok{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25);color:black}
            .bogus{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25);color:white}
            label{display:inline-block;width:calc(50% - 4px);clear:none;margin:auto;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                const oPick=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="pick"]');
                const oDrop=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="drop"]');
                const oResults=[];
                
                const BerlinRegion = [
                    { lat: 53.804069, lng: 14.124429 },
                    { lat: 52.016925, lng: 13.959028 },
                    { lat: 52.037322, lng: 11.438104 },
                    { lat: 52.888570, lng: 8.804136 },
                    { lat: 54.148454, lng: 9.626415 }
                ];
                
                /* create basic map */
                const latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 );
                const options = {
                    zoom: 1,
                    center:latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                const map=new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                const bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                
                
                /* ensure we see the BerlinArea entirely */
                BerlinRegion.forEach( obj=>{
                    bounds.extend( obj );
                });
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
                
                /* display the area of operations */
                let polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    path: BerlinRegion,
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#00FF00',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#00FF00',
                    fillOpacity: 0.1,
                    map:map
                }); 
                
                
                const changehandler=function(){
                    // the same event handler can perform this task for both pickup & dropoff
                    let res=google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation( this.getPlace().geometry.location, polygon );
                    return testresults( res );
                };
                const addresult=function( res ){
                    // if the array is longer than 2, remove elements from the start of the array
                    while( oResults.length >= 2 )oResults.shift();
                    // add new item
                    oResults.push( res );
                };
                const testresults=function(r){
                    addresult(r);
                    
                    let b=false;//default return value
                    let a=[ ...new Set( oResults ) ];// create an array of unique elements using the `splat` operator and `Set`
                    if( oResults.length==2 ) b=a.length==2; // to be valid we need true & false in the array - hence a length of 2
                    if( oResults.length==2 )indicate( b ); // let user know selection is valid / invalid
                    return b;
                };
                const indicate=function(status){
                    [oPick,oDrop].forEach(el=>{
                        el.className=status ? 'ok' : 'bogus'
                    })
                };
                
                
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( oPick ).addListener('place_changed',changehandler);
                new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( oDrop ).addListener('place_changed',changehandler);
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&callback=initMap&libraries=places'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <form>
            <label>Collect from:<input type='text' name='pick' /></label>
            <label>Deliver to:<input type='text' name='drop' /></label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's almost perfect, how can i make this to wait for te second input? right now is showing the alert after completed only first input

Comment: I'll have a wee think

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: perhaps consider upvoting/accepting answer?!